# Cannot print the output of the given node. The root Element can only be printed

Tags: java, xml

I'm just starting to learn JAVA xml = DOM4J which is based on TutorialsPoint is much more flexible of parsing a xml code. So I focused on understanding more the DOM4J because of it's less coding compared to DOM parser and JDOM.

I have a problem in printing the output of the Node. Any help would appreciate! Please bear with me since I am still learning how to use it and be more familiarize with it. For more understanding kindly explain in an easy how to execute it properly. Thank you!

My code based from TutorialsPoint

```
try {
        String src = "student.xml";
        File inputFile = new File(src);
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

        Document doc = reader.read(inputFile);

        System.out.println("Root element: "
                + doc.getRootElement().getName());

        Element classElement = doc.getRootElement();

        List<Node> nodes = doc.selectNodes("/Section/Student");

        for (Node node : nodes){
            System.out.println("First Name" + node.selectSingleNode("FirstName").getText());
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Section>

<Student>
    <Idnumber>0000001</Idnumber>
    <FirstName>Cat</FirstName>
    <LastName>Dog</LastName>
</Student>
</Section>
```

The errors I have receiving in the console are the following:

`Root element :Section
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/jaxen/JaxenException
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
    at com.dls.csb.ParsingXML.main(ParsingXML.java:30)`

Comment: Are you deploying the application on a server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote a [TutorialsPoint article on dom4j](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom4j_parser.htm):

> In order to use DOM4J parser, you should have dom4j-1.6.1.jar and jaxen.jar in your application's classpath.

Evidently you don't have the jaxen jar in your classpath.  If you have the dom4j-1.6.1.zip archive, you can find a jaxen jar in the `lib` folder.

I took your code and ran it with the jaxen jar on the classpath and it ran successfully.  Your code appears to be doing what you want, you just don't quite have all of the dependencies.

Jaxen is a Java XPath library, and the text `/Section/Student` within the line

```
        List<Node> nodes = doc.selectNodes("/Section/Student");
```

is an XPath expression that selects all `Student` elements that are children of the root `Section` element.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out before I got here. I forgot to add the jaxen.jar, I just have the dom4j jar. I have a question too, what about the other jar files? Not necessary?

Comment: @user3323654: it depends on what you want to do.  Other JARs appear to include functionality for validating against XML schema or Relax NG, and if you're not doing either of those things then you won't need those JARs.  For the time being, don't add any other JARs to the classpath.  If you later run into a NoClassDefFoundError, have a search through these JARs to see if one of them contains the class the JVM was complaining it couldn't find, and if so, add that JAR to the classpath.